# React-Router: Adding in a landing page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, url-routing

With React-Router there is a nesting concept that makes it hard for me to imagine where I should inject my landing page.

For example:

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="login" component={Login} />
      <Route path="logout" component={Logout} />
      <Route path="about" component={About} />
      <Route path="dashboard" component={Dashboard} onEnter={requireAuth} />
</Route>
```

In that example part of the top-level component is shared with the rest of the components.

But with a landing page, there might not be the parent-child relationship for you to fit it into the routing.

Ergo, how do you manage putting in a landing page when using react-router?

Comment: you could use `IndexRoute` to solve that

Comment: @knowbody but doesn't IndexRoute have the same nesting concept behind it? The landing page has it's own structure outside of the rest of the app.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, let me answer here then.

The way you could do it is pretty straight forward, I think, if I understood you correctly.
I would do something like:

```jsx
<Route path='/' component={LandingPage}>
  <Route path='app' component={App}>
    <Route path="login" component={Login} />
    <Route path="logout" component={Logout} />
    <Route path="about" component={About} />
    <Route path="dashboard" component={Dashboard} onEnter={requireAuth} />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

and then only include `this.props.children` in your `App` component.

Comment: but wouldn't the landing page code be throughout the entire project then? Like at each layer some code stays and this "this.props.children" is filled in based on the current route?

Comment: I don't think I understand your question... What landing page code?

Comment: It's a separate component that doesn't share the same structure that the rest of the code has. For instance- the rest of my app has a header, the landing page doesn't.

Comment: that's ok. you include all of your "structure" in the `App` component

Comment: I tried this technique and it works for me! Thanks, somebody.

Comment: the problem of this technique is that all routes include a /app/ which might not always be desired

Comment: @mezod what you can do is leave the top level route without the path and change the inner route's path from `app` to `/`

Comment: yeah I learnt that from the answer below immediately after posting, thanks man! :)

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get any of the above answers to work so I decided to just do it my way. Here is what I did:

```
<Route path="/">
  <IndexRoute component={Landing}/>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <Route path="login" component={LoginOrRegister} onEnter={redirectAuth}/>
    <Route path="dashboard" component={Dashboard} onEnter={requireAuth}/>
    <Route path="vote" component={Vote} onEnter={requireAuth}/>
    <Route path="about" component={About}/>
  </Route>
</Route>
```

The Main component contains the minimal required for both the landing page and the App itself. In my case, they share nothing so the component is simply a wrapping div.

```
const Main = ({children}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {children}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this with the latest version (v6) of `react-router-dom` which no longer supports `IndexRoute`. After trying a few different approaches, it turned out to be relatively simple to add to the final catch-all where we normally specify our 404 page...

```
<Switch>
    <Route
        path="/learn?"
        component={Learn}
    />
    <Private
        path="/search?"
        component={Search}
    />
    <Route
        component={match.isExact ? Landing : Lost}
    />
</Switch>
```

This is within a top-level `Application` component that handles the root (`/`) path so `match.isExact` means we're on the home page. Above and below the `<Switch>` you can render any elements present on every page (e.g. a `header` and `footer`).

Hope this helps anyone coming across this question in 2022 and beyond.

Answer (score 1):

React-router V6 supports index as an attribute of Route component

Index Route - A child route with no path that renders in the parent's outlet at the parent's URL.

See docs https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts under "Defining Route" heading.

````
  <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
    <Route index element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="teams" element={<Teams />}>
      <Route path=":teamId" element={<Team />} />
    ...
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Routes>```
````

Answer (score 0):

The IndexRoute in React-Router lets you define the default component when reaching a portion of your application. So with the following code, if you go to "/", the page will render the `App` component and inject the `LandingPage` component into its props.children.

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={LandingPage} />
    <Route path="login" component={Login} />
    <Route path="logout" component={Logout} />
    <Route path="about" component={About} />
    <Route path="dashboard" component={Dashboard} onEnter={requireAuth} />
</Route>
```